# Calculating average raster from two other rasters using Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have to calculate an average raster from 4 rasters. I have tried in ArcMap with Raster Calculator but the result is wrong. It's a line. I'm sure that I've done something wrong, but I don't know what.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried. In raster calculator all you have to do is add the rasters and divide by the number of rasters.  (X1 + X2 +  X3) / 3

Comment: Adding images showing your raster data and the erroneous results would also help.

Comment: Without further information, it is only speculation but, the raster calculator honors the established analysis environment. If not defined correctly you can receive wonky output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Cell Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) tool if you don't want to build the expression in raster calculator and set the statistics type parameter to MEAN.